# WCF Serialization of POCOs

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I'm rewriting part of an MVVM application so that a WCF service sits between the ViewModel and the Model.

I know that I'll need to move database interaction code from the VM to the service, and then rewrite the remaining VM to interact with service proxy objects and the service rather than the model.

The proxy classes generated by WCF's service reference are horrendous, though - all have "k_BackingField" appended. I found this link (http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/wcf-data-contracts-and-k__backingfield-property-naming/) which seems to provide a workaround, wherein you decorate the classes to explicitly provide information to the serializer instead of having it infer. I did this for the class I'm working with, and it caused no difference in the service reference. The exact same weird field names are present, etc..

How can I remove "k_BackingField" from my POCO proxies? I wish I could just deserialize back into the same POCO model classes instead of a service-reference-level proxy, so if that's an option I'd prefer that even more.

In case this is relevant, here's some details about the setup:
- Model is code-first EF6 (latest).
- Model uses repository pattern with a generic Repository with a type argument.
- WCF service has direct access to the model project and uses it in its code.
- VM has direct access to the model project and used(?) (in process of rewriting) it in its code.
- VM has a service reference to the WCF service done via the VS UI.

Comment: Are you using [WCF OData](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2013/10/02/using-wcf-data-services-5-6-0-with-entity-framework-6.aspx) with EF? That is the preferred way you are supposed to do EF and WCF interactions.

Comment: If you add this as an answer I'll accept it as the answer, as this bypassed the problem entirely for me.

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework does not recommend mixing traditional WCF and EF, you run in to issues with navigation properties like you found out. What they recommend is you use [WCF Data Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/odata) instead. [Here is a tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg601462) from the Data services website to get you started.